# Why do I get a "Call to a member function getObject() on null" error message on AWS S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

When using the below PHP code (as per latest AWS PHP SDK) to access a file in an AWS S3 bucket:

```php
try {
    $img_file_cmd = $s3client_to_get_files->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $s3_bucket_name,
        'Key' => s3_file_path
    ]);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo "Failed with error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getObject() on null

I don't get back any Exception, and instead, I get the Uncaught Error as above.

Same AWS user and policy are successfully used in other part of the app. The policy of course has the `listBucket` and `getObject` capabilities. Checked and echoed, `s3_bucket_name` and `s3_file_path` are correct.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The message clearly says that `$s3client_to_get_files` is null.

Comment: If it was so, a catch Exception should be fired. No catch Exception fired instead

Comment: The [`Error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) class does not extend `Exception` (it directly implements `Throwable`).

Comment: Thx Olivier. So I'll investigate what's goin' on by the aws client